# Will I have to go through Customs at Heathrow?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, spain, england

I will be flying Virgin Atlantic from Boston and then connecting with British Airways to Barcelona.

I don't know if I'll be able to bypass customs and rechecking my bag? I have given myself enough time just in case.

Any help will be great.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Airlines can often _interline_ perfectly well without codesharing (and as far as I know Virgin is not so low-cost that they don't codeshare).

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Just because their own customer-facing web frontend won't offer interlined itineraries doesn't mean they can't be issued through a GDS.

Comment: Yes, I found it. Apparently it's too late in the night for me to be trying to look up flights.

Comment: Boston, Heathrow and Barcelona are big airports with many flights. _Surely_ you can get a good deal Boston-Barcelona without needing to buy separate tickets. Being on one ticket is much safer: your bags are automatically checked through and, more importantly, you're guaranteed to be put on a later flight if your first flight is delayed and you miss your connection. On two tickets, if your first flight is delayed, the airline running the second flight is entitled to say, "Tough. It was your responsibility to be here on time. We don't care you were coming from Boston instead of somewhere local."

Comment: Are these two flights on one ticket or are they on two tickets? (In a nutshell: did you pay once or twice?)